# iptables matched rule

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04

If a rule matched to packet and it has `-j DROP`, I know that the packet will stop to traverse throughout the rest of the rules. However I don't understand what will happen if the packet will match a rule with -j ACCEPT? Would it again stop to traverse throughout the rules or it will try to match other rules? In other words what will happen if a pcket has many rules to match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First match wins, and processing stops if the target is a "terminating" target; those include `DROP`, `ACCEPT`, `DNAT`, and so on.  They are targets that make a determination about the final disposition of the packet; there is no sense in saying `-j REJECT` if it can be overridden three lines later with `-j OH-SORRY-I-DIDNT-MEAN-IT`.

First match wins, and processing does **not** stop if the target is "non-terminating"; those include `LOG`, `ULOG`, and sending the packet to a user-defined chain.  In that latter case, processing continues through the rules in that chain, and if none matches with a terminating target, the packet "falls out the bottom of the chain" and returns to the rule in the calling chain after the one that sent it to the user-defined chain.

Is that clear?  First-match-wins **always** applies, which is why the order of rules is important.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there are 2 kinds of iptables targets:

- Non-terminating targets (e.g., LOG, ULOG, TOS, MARK, CONNMARK, NOTRACK, CONNTRACK)
- Terminating targets (e.g. ACCEPT, DROP, REJECT)

**Non-terminating** means, after a certain action has been applied, the packet continues to the next **rule** in the **same chain/table**

**Terminating** means, after a certain action has been applied, processing ends **on that *table***. If the packet still exists, the packet will then continue to the next table according to the netfilter flow sequence (see below). Of course, in the cases of REJECT and DROP, the packet no longer exist, so naturally there will be no more processing.

The [wikipedia article on iptables](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) provides a diagram on the sequence of tables/chains a packet will encounter.